# VHDL ALU, 8-bit register

Tags: vhdl

The following VHDL design is meant to do the operation as shown in the diagram but the simulated waveform doesn't seem to be correct. I've spent hours but can't spot the mistake.

[image]

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity LU is
port(
CLK       :in  std_logic;                      -- System Clock
RES       :in  std_logic;                      -- Synchronous reset
OPCODE    :in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);   -- Logic Unit Opcode
A         :in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- A input bus
B         :in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- B input bus
Q         :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)    -- Q output from Logic Unit     
);
               
end LU;

architecture behavioral of LU is
signal QA,Aa,Bb : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin


Aa<=A;
Bb<=B;
process(clk)
begin

if RES = '1' then
  QA <= "00000000" ;
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
  case OPCODE is
        when "000" => 
            QA <= not(Aa);  
        when "001" => 
            QA <= not( Aa xor Bb);
        when "010" => 
            QA <= not(Aa or Bb); 
        when "011" => 
            QA <= not( Aa and Bb);
        when "100" => 
            QA <= Aa;              
        when "101" => 
            QA <= ( Aa xor Bb); 
        when "110" => 
            QA <= ( Aa or Bb);   
        when "111" => 
            QA <= ( Aa and Bb); 
        when others =>
            NULL;
    end case;
 Q<= QA ;
 end if ;
 end process ;
 end behavioral;
```

[image]

That's the wave after I tried moving Q <= QA assignment to outside of the process.

[image: wave]

Comment: Move your 'Q <= QA' assignment to outside of your process so its a concurrent statement. Where it is, it's implying a second set of DFFs that you don't want. (You don't actually need QA, you can more tidily assign directly to Q in your process. Similar thing goes for Aa and Bb.)

Comment: What about that "synchronous reset"? Shouldn't your test for RES be inside the rising_edge test?

Comment: I moved Q <= QA outside of the process but waveform seems incorrect still...

Comment: This seems eerily familiar. Do you happen to study at the EPFL? I would suggest separating combinatorial from sequential logic in 2 different process. It usually clarifies things.

Comment: The second waveform diagram looks correct to me. Which part is wrong?

Comment: I agree with Entrepreneur, it looks correct to me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem that you're seeing is due to the unnecessary stage that your signal `QA` generates - declared here:

> signal QA,Aa,Bb : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

Your `OPCODE` selects an assignment for `QA` on one clock cycle which, in turn, assigns the final output `Q` on the **following** clock cycle.

A cleaner approach would be to eliminate all of the internal signals, which are altogether unnecessary for your `LU` entity.

Try this instead:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity LU is
port(
    CLK       :in  std_logic;                      -- System Clock
    RES       :in  std_logic;                      -- Synchronous reset
    OPCODE    :in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);   -- Logic Unit Opcode
    A         :in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- A input bus
    B         :in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   -- B input bus
    Q         :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));  -- Q output from Logic Unit     
end LU;

architecture behavioral of LU is
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if RES = '1' then
                Q <= (others => '0');
            else
              case OPCODE is
                    when "000" => 
                        Q <= not(A);  
                    when "001" => 
                        Q <= not(A xor B);
                    when "010" => 
                        Q <= not(A or B); 
                    when "011" => 
                        Q <= not(A and B);
                    when "100" => 
                        Q <= A;              
                    when "101" => 
                        Q <= (A xor B); 
                    when "110" => 
                        Q <= (A or B);   
                    when "111" => 
                        Q <= (A and B); 
                    when others =>
                        Q <= (others => '0');
                end case;
            end if;
         end if;
     end process;
 end behavioral;
```

Which produces the correct RTL:
[image: Correct RTL]

With this simulation:
[image: Correct simulation]

---

**Your VHDL yields this RTL:**
[image: Incorrect RTL]

There are *three* things to notice here:

1. Your extra `QA` signal ends up generating an undesired 2<sup>nd</sup> stage of gates
2. The 2<sup>nd</sup> stage of gates is improperly enabled. Notice that your `RES` signal ends up acting as an inverted clock enable on the final gates? This is due to the fact that your final output `Q` is not assigned a value during your `RES = 1` condition. Your code only actually assigns `Q` within the `elsif rising_edge(clk) then` clause. This leads to a poor design. If a signal is assigned a value in one case (or if-then level), it should be assigned a value in all of them. Otherwise you will end up with latches or inappropriate CE signals.
3. You should use synchronous resets (as I did in the above code). Short of that, a good convention to use is

   - Name the signal **CLR** for asynchronous operations
   - Name the signal **RST** for synchronous operations

Notice, that this is the convention employed by Xilinx, as you can confirm by comparing the two RTL diagrams.

Comment: How do Aa and Bb introduce DFFs? QA - yes. Aa and Bb are concurrent assignments.

Comment: @TonyM They don’t. I avoided specifically stating which signal created the DFFs in attempt to encourage the OP to simplify. But you’re right; I should probably clean up the wording.

Comment: Dv answer because of the confusion in your wrong answer. Will remove dv once you've corrected the answer.

Comment: @TonyM Fair enough. Answer has been edited. Thanks for catching that.